# Chrome: Google Maps API JS Loading Issue with https

Tags: php, javascript, google-chrome, https, sugarcrm

I've got an open source package that I've worked on for SugarCRM that uses the Google Map API. Users have reported that there is a bug with the Chrome Browser (https loading issue). The problem occurs when the SugarCRM URL is defined with the https protocol and the Maps API URL is http. Because this is an installed package, it may be used with a http or https protocol; it depends on where it's installed.

Example SugarCRM URL:

```
https://www.mydomain.com/index.php
```

Current Google Maps API Call:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

I'm considering simply changing it to https, but will that fix issue? Should I instead write some logic to check the site's URL (from SugarCRM config) for http or https and make it matching protocols? What about other external JS files such as jquery?

Also, I've seen people using // which is supposed to let the browser decided on the protocol? Is that compatible with all the latest browsers; such as Firefox, IE, Chrome & Safari?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a Protocol Relative URL (i.e. the //) is I believe supported in pretty much all recent mainstream browsers (except possibly IE6) so I would say it's perfectly safe. You can read more about them from Paul Irish here: http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/

If you did want to do a check yourself it is a fairly simple check in javascript, something like this but obviously for maps instead of ga:

```
ga.src = ('https:' == location.protocol ? '//ssl' : '//www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
```

(as found here: http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/async-analytics-snippet#protocol-check)

Note that if you're on google maps API v2 I think you had to do it this way as the url was different for ssl, but it looks like you're on the current version so should be fine.

I believe twitter used to have a check like the one above for their tweet buttons but now use protocol relative urls too. The [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) template also uses then so I'd say you're in good company if you decide to use them.